# JS + JQ событие клавиш

Tags: javascript, jquery

Код регистрирующий событие нажатие клавиши реагирует после однакратного клика на документе.

В чем тонкость?
Интересующий кусок:

```
$( window ).keydown(function( viewPage ) {
    if ( viewPage.keyCode == 74 ) {
        $('a').text( numberPicture );
    }
    //to left
    if ( viewPage.keyCode == 37 ) {

    }
    //to right
    else  if ( viewPage.keyCode == 39 ) {

    }
});
```

```js
//JQ
$( document ).ready(function() {
    
   var numberPicture = 0;
      
 var start = 0, timeScroll = 150,
     denominator = 1.6, description = $(".js-description>p"),
        baseline = $( window ).height() / denominator;       
     
 $( document ).on('scroll', function() {
     $( document ).click();
     if ( $(this).scrollTop() > baseline ) {
         if ( start == numberPicture ) {
          description.eq( start ).fadeIn( timeScroll );
         } else {
             description.eq( numberPicture ).fadeIn( timeScroll );
            }
        } else {
         description.fadeOut( timeScroll );
        }
    });
    
    
    
    var section = 2, timeText = 100,
        cssMinus = "-=100%", styleShift = "swing",
        out$a = ":first-child", out$b = ":last-child",
        timeSlide = 500, cssZero = 0, cssPlus = "+=100%",
        clickHere = $("img.picture"), pictureBox = $(".js-exhibition"),
        middle =  pictureBox.width() / section;
        
    clickHere.on('click', function( exhibition ) {
      
          numberPicture = $(this).index();
         
          var feeling = exhibition.pageX;
            if ( feeling > middle){
             if ( $(this).is( out$b )){
                 $(this).add($(this).prev()).animate({ left: cssPlus}, timeSlide);
                     description.eq( numberPicture ).add(description.eq( --numberPicture )).fadeToggle( timeText, styleShift);
                } else {
              $(this).add($(this).next()).animate({ left: cssMinus}, timeSlide);
                    description.eq( numberPicture++ ).add(description.eq( numberPicture )).fadeToggle( timeText, styleShift);
     
             }}
            if ( feeling < middle ) {
             if ( $(this).is( out$a )){
                 $(this).add($(this).next()).animate({ left: cssMinus}, timeSlide);
                    description.eq( numberPicture++ ).add(description.eq( numberPicture )).fadeToggle( timeText, styleShift);
                    //$('a').text(numberPicture++);
                } else {
              $(this).add($(this).prev()).animate({ left: cssPlus}, timeSlide);
                    description.eq( numberPicture ).add(description.eq( --numberPicture )).fadeToggle( timeText, styleShift);
                   
            }}
    });

    $( window ).keydown(function( viewPage ) {
     if ( viewPage.keyCode == 74 ) {
         $('a').text( numberPicture );
        }
        //to left
        if ( viewPage.keyCode == 37 ) {
         
        }
        //to right
        else  if ( viewPage.keyCode == 39 ) {
       
     }
    }); 
});
```

```css
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
body{ background:rgb(46,46,46);
}
.js-description {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 3;
}

.js-description>p {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    color: black;
    width: 30vw;
    top:0;
}

.js-description>p:nth-child(3) {
    color: black;
}

.js-exhibition {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 96vh;
}

img.picture {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100vw;
    left: 100vw;
}

img.picture:nth-child(1) {
    left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="js-description">
    <p class="indent">
        Head<br>Text - 1<br>
        <a class="material-icons" href="#">x</a>
    </p>
    <p class="indent">
        Head<br>Text - 2<br>
        <a class="material-icons" href="#">x</a>
    </p>
    <p class="indent">
        Head<br>Text -3<br>
        <a class="material-icons" href="#">x</a>
    </p>
</div>

<div class="js-exhibition">
    <img class="picture" src="https://mir-s3-cdn-cf.behance.net/project_modules/max_1200/1c3d6a34857211.56e04e5a16466.jpg" alt="X5 Retail Group" />
    <img class="picture" src="https://mir-s3-cdn-cf.behance.net/project_modules/max_1200/06f6e534857211.56e04e5a17d48.jpg" alt="Кофейная компания — Музей" />
    <img class="picture" src="https://mir-s3-cdn-cf.behance.net/project_modules/max_1200/e9b1a534857211.56e04e5a169cc.jpg" alt="Мыс Когг" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вполне логично, ведь событие keydown работает только при фокусе на конкретном элементе.

```
<input type="password"/>
<script>
    (function() {
        const input = document.querySelector("input[type=password]");
        input.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
            const { key } = e;
            console.log(key);
        });
    })();
</script>
```